# Python RegExpression Not Working according to need

Tags: regex, filesystems

```
import re
print sorted( re.findall(r'\b[abcABC][\w-]+' ,open("file.txt",'r').read()))
```

---

file.txt includes:

```
aaa
autonomic-ads-bgl
academy
bfc
bhhuu
cgak
ctsss
dec-ama-cdr
dfgg-hhj-bhjk
efghk-cgh-hghj
pattern-bgl-fghhj
```

Output:

```
aaa
academy
ama-cdr
autonomic-ads-bgl
bfc
bhhuu
bgl-fghhj
cgak
cgh-hghj
ctsss
```

But required output is sorted elements from a to c

```
aaa
academy
autonomic-ads-bgl
bfc
bhhuu
cgak
ctsss
```

Answer (score 0):

You may exclude all entries that have a hyphen before with a negative lookbehind:

```
print sorted(re.findall(r'(?<!-)\b[abcABC][\w-]+' ,s))
                          ^^^^^^
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q4lzgy)

**Details**:

- `(?<!-)` - the negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a `-` right before the current regex index (location)
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `[abcABC]` - one of the characters in the set
- `[\w-]+` - 1 or more word or `-` characters.

Note that in case your words do not start with a word boundary and there just should be whitespace or start of the string, you can use `(?<!\S)` lookbehind instead of `(?<!-)\b` ([demo](https://ideone.com/hRPDIz)):

```
r'(?<!\S)[abcABC][\w-]+'
```